# Why does the apk abort only in the release version on Android 10?

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, native, abort

I'm using Unity 2018.4 to make a 2D game. I am facing a strange error with native code (possibly coming from some library) only in a release version and possibly in Android 10.

I don't know how to interpret the abort message.

[Abort message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldXQ0.jpg)

The only library I used that doesn't start with Unity is `libsqlite3.so` extracted from the SQLite website itself. ([Link](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) here)

I also have the errors coming from Google Play by Android Vitals, but it’s just as unreadable.

Does anyone know how I can solve? My game is already in the Play Store and I am receiving some complaints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was suspecting was correct, the problem was the 64x library `libsqlite3.so`, I didn't quite understand what might have happened, I replaced the library with one from [this](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-unity-sdk/issues/1331) source.

Answer (score 0):

`SIGSEGV`, nice. Welcome to the club of games programmers who have managed to really crash Android hard. I've got a couple of guesses, but can't say for certain. More info would be useful - is this happening to all users of your release, or just some devices or device families?

I've managed to do the same, but my crash was consistent - happened every time, not just release. I had some `libGDX` native objects open, then tried to change the activity before closing them. My crash looked quite like yours. Check your screen changes to make sure that you cleanly close all your objects before trying to change activities/fragments.

The fact that you mention release makes me think of ProGuard. If you have it turned on it can aggressively optimise out classes that are 'unused'. This means that if you have classes you use via reflection then they won't be compiled into the release bundle. You could try turning it off completely and making a release, to see if that makes things work again. If this is the cause, look into

`-keepclasseswithmembers class [your_class_path].** {*;}`

in your `proguard-rules.pro`.

Comment: Thank you to answer. Sorry for not understanding very well but how can I clean these objects? As far as I know Unity compiles just one Activity, the UnityPlayerActivity. The error occurs usually on 64-bit phones with Android 10 when the scene changes.

Comment: In that case I have no idea sorry. Mine were parts of the draw/render subsystems and I just had to close them with `object.close();`